# how to execute script on zabbix agent?

Tags: zabbix

I have made a magic script on Zabbix agent and i wanna to execute on Zabbix agent using Zabbix item.i will be thankful to you in advance for this . do something if you can.

Answer (score 2):

You would create a [user parameter](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/userparameters) that would look like any other item from the server side. On the agent side, you would have to edit the agent configuration file and restart the agent.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to user parameters, Zabbix supports remote commands.  These are appropriate (and indeed invoked from) actions as a result of some condition.  So in the answer from Richv you would use that for polling for data, e.g. to find out if a process is running.  Continuing that example, if the process is not running and you wanted to start it, you can ask the agent to execute a command that might start the process. To do that you must enable remote commands in the agent config file, and configure it as an action (that in turn is linked to whatever condition you had concerns about).

Answer (score 0):

1st in the zabbix_agentd.conf for the remote host, add `EnableRemoteCommands=1`

Then see the video at https://youtu.be/G6jfahBZwlk

[image]

In the video, a bat file is created on the remote host, and then an item is created for the remote host using the Zabbix server interface, and selecting the `system.run` option in the key options.